# Using JSON-PATH with SnakeYAML

Tags: java, jsonpath, snakeyaml

I am trying to find a way to use JSON-PATH with SnakeYaml in order to select node and to still get a way to find the line number inside the yaml source file.

For example the path `$.info.email` will tell me that it's `line 16` (for example) of the source file, read by snakeyaml.

I am able to navigate inside the nodes given by Snakeyaml (`ScalarNode`, `MappedNode`, etc.) and Snakeyaml offers a way (`Mark`) to get the line number of a node.

So I need a way to be able to use a json-path expression in roder to point inside the node tree of Snakeyaml.

I thought I can use `JsonProvider` and a `MappingProvider` from json-path, but things are not very clear to me and the Javadoc is quite silent about this topic.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

It is not yet implemented in SnakeYAML.